# Metal nail reaction in wall filler

Tags: metal

[image]

Please help explain what is happening to this nail. It has been in this wall filler for a good few months.

The substance being excreted was rising up forming these stalagmites, with a liquid forming on them.

Removing the nail, there were also excretions at the part that was sunken.

Comment: What exactly is "wall filler"?

Comment: Sorry there is no chemical composition on the products label. Its used to fill up cracks in the wall... so a type of cement that hardens once applied to a surface.

Comment: Do you have a name for the product so we can look up its composition?

Comment: This is the product: http://durapaints.co.za/product/prolong-supafill/ might have to contact the company for chemical breakdown.

Comment: That's probably regular gypsum (drywall) then.

Answer (score 2):

It is such a beautiful picture, perhaps good for a chemistry book cover. It is a similar phenomenon as what happens in a so-called chemical garden. Water seems to be creeping up to the nail head, and helping in oxidation of iron salts to insoluble hydroxides. Finally the gelatinous membranes act like semi-permeable membranc in the osmosis like experiment. [image: Garden]

The figure shows several salt crystals soaked in a slightly alkaline medium.

Ref: From Chemical Gardens to Chemobrionics,Chemical Reviews, 2015, 115(16)
DOI: 10.1021/acs.chemrev.5b00014

Comment: Thanks for the comments - don't know much about chemistry but your answer does sound good. There does still seem to be some unknowns, but I guess that is why it is called a phenomenon.